# Query to get total distinct values side by side with group by values

Tags: sql, count, apache-spark-sql, distinct

How do I get a column that shows a count of total distinct values side by side with a "group by" count of distinct values.

For example, in the query below I'm getting counts of distinct patients in each value set.  I would also like to get the total count of distinct patients as well.  How do I do this?  The query below works but does not get me the counts for the total number of patients.  This happens to be in Databricks SQL/Apache Spark but I imagine has a generalized solution across most sql database implementations.

```
select
  value_set_name,
  oid value_set_oid,
  count(distinct rx.patient_id) as count
  -- ??? count of total distinct patient_id's ???
from
  rx
  join value_set vs on rx.code = vs.code
group by 1,2
order by 1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery is possibly the simplest method:

```
select value_set_name,
       oid as value_set_oid,
       count(distinct rx.patient_id) as count,
       (select count(distinct rx2.patient_id) from rx rx2) as num_total_distinct
  -- ??? count of total distinct patient_id's ???
from rx join
     value_set vs
     on rx.code = vs.code
group by 1,2
order by 1;
```

Because you are using `count(distinct)`, you cannot simply sum the total `count(distinct)`s from all rows -- patients in more than on group would be counted multiple times.

Your query is actually pretty simple.  It might be faster to do two levels of aggregation:

```
select value_set_name, value_set_oid, count(*) as num_patients,
       sum(count(*)) over () as num_total_patients
from (select value_set_name, oid as value_set_oid, rx_patient_id, count(*) as cnt
      from rx join
           value_set vs
           on rx.code = vs.code
      group by 1, 2, 3
     ) rv
group by 1, 2
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want window functions?

```
select
    value_set_name,
    oid as value_set_oid,
    count(distinct rx.patient_id) as cnt_distinct_patient
    sum(count(distinct rx.patient_id)) over() as total_cnt_distinct_patient
from rx
inner join value_set vs on rx.code = vs.code
group by 1, 2
order by 1
```

Comment: This worked but the count I got for total_cnt_distinct_patient was not what I expcted (not the same as select count(distinct_patient_id).  I'll have to look into this solution further.  Thanks for the help!